# decode unicode string with javascript without JSON

Tags: javascript, unicode

i want to decode the string such us: \u003cPoint x\u003d\"214\"

What is the best javascript library for this purpose?

Comment: What is the format if it is not JSON? There are many string literal formats with `\u` escapes, all with slightly different rules. For example what does `\"` mean? or double-backslash? Or `\x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
var x = "\u003cPoint x\u003d\"214\"";
var r = /\\u([\d\w]{4})/gi;
x = x.replace(r, function (match, grp) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(grp, 16)); } );
x = unescape(x);
console.log(x);
```

Comment: thanks for the rapid response.

Comment: That should be "var r = /\\u([\d]{4})/gi;"  Otherwise it will match "\Users" in the text.  (Yeah, that was painful)